# How to spawn object on mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I click right click I want to create new sphere. And I don't know why this don't work. It creates a sphere, but definitely not on mouse position!

```
Vector2 mousePos;
public Transform mousePointer;
float mouseX, mouseY;
Vector3 spawnPoint;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;
        spawnPoint = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
        Instantiate(mousePointer, spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try spawning the object relative to the camera.

For example, use `spawnPoint = cameraPosition + new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);` or something similar. Check out the related post: [Create a cube relative to camera mouse position](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/447953/create-a-primitive-placed-relative-to-camera-mouse.html).

The object is being spawned in global coordinates.